# Can the ifTrue be omitted from an if in smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk

Usually an if in Smalltalk looks like this

```
condition
        ifTrue: [ ... ]
        ifFalse: [ ... ].
```

However, I can not find whether it is allowed to omit one of the parts, such as `ifTrue: ..` or `ifFalse ..`.

Is there a manual that I am missing? I cannot find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pharo Smalltalk for example knows

- `ifTrue:`
- `ifTrue:ifFalse:`
- `ifFalse:`
- `ifFalse:ifTrue:`

I think other dialects understand similar messages. They are part of the [ANSI Smalltalk Standard](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/uploads/172/standard_v1_9-indexed.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! Where can I find such information? Ah okay, in the standard!

Comment: In the documentation of your Smalltalk of choice, in the [ANSI Smalltalk Standard](http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/uploads/172/standard_v1_9-indexed.pdf) or in your Smalltalk system browser, in the protocol of the class `Boolean`.

Comment: These methods are defined on `Boolean` class, just browse that class.